# NoClassDefFoundError при инициализации HibernateSessionFactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Объясните пожалуйста, я совсем новичок во всем что выходит за рамки java core. 
Проблема следующая при запуске webapp на tomcat вылетает exception.
Как исправить, не понимаю.

исходный код разместил на [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dewy8qk7oah1f81/AADQiBi9taPt90DW7vj1C6tAa?dl=0)

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class ru.haki.utils.HibernateSessionFactory
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1305)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    root cause

    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class ru.haki.utils.HibernateSessionFactory
        ru.haki.service.UserService.getAllUsers(UserService.java:27)
        ru.haki.controller.MainController.main(MainController.java:24)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка `Could not initialize class ru.haki.utils.HibernateSessionFactory` возникает из-за замаскированного падения при инициализации статического поля `sessionFactory` в этом коде.

```
try {
    session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
    session.getTransaction().begin();
    users = session.createQuery("FROM User").list();
} catch(HibernateException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    HibernateSessionFactory.closeSession(session);
}
```

При первом обращении к `HibernateSessionFactory` т.е. при вызове `session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();` возникает ошибка инициализации, но т.к. в блоке `finally` есть повторное обращение к `HibernateSessionFactory` который уже пытались безуспешно проинициализировать, то исходная ошибка маскируется, а выбрасыается исключение `NoClassDefFoundError`. Если закомментировать вызов `HibernateSessionFactory.closeSession(session);` то можно увидеть исходное исключение

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.StrategyRegistrationProvider: Provider org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.StrategyRegistrationProviderImpl not found
    java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
    java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(Unknown Source)
    java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:340)
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorBuilder.buildSelector(StrategySelectorBuilder.java:162)
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:222)
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:58)
    ru.haki.utils.HibernateSessionFactory.buildSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:19)
```

по которому, к сожалению, подсказать не могу.

*На будущее.*
Старайтесь избегать самодельных Singleton объектов (если всё же  есть необходимость, почитайте [эту статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/129494/)) а пользуйтесь возможностями, предоставляемыми используемыми фреймворками, в вашем случае Spring. А код инициализации HibernateSessionFactory советую вынести в статический бок инициализации как-то так:

```
public class HibernateSessionFactory {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

    {
        try {
            sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //TODO: добавить логирование
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Хотя правильнее, на мой взгляд, из этого сделать Spring Bean.

Comment: Не подскажите правильную статью по Spring Bean?

Comment: Официальная документация [здесь (англ.)](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html). Неплохой урок на русском [здесь](http://spring-projects.ru/guides/lessons/lesson-2/)

Comment: Через бины сделал. Проблема аналогичная